# No Permission to /dev/ttyUSB on Debian

Tags: serial-port, raspberry-pi, usb, debian

I am using Debian 8.0 and have a USB->Serial Port Adapter

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
```

It is listed in /dev/ as ttyUSB0, but i can't use ist.
I am in the group 'dialout', too.

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Jan  4 10:38 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

If i try to use it by

```
/dev/ttyUSB0
```

the output is (no permission):

```
-bash: /dev/ttyUSB0: Keine Berechtigung
```

I tried reboots and so an, but it won't work. 
Is there anyone with an idea for this problem?

Comment: What does the `groups` command give you as result?

Comment: pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev gpio i2c spi

Answer (score 2):

The message `/dev/ttyUSB0: Keine Berechtigung` (permission denied) is telling you, that your group lacks the `x` permission. Nevertheless, it is kind of missleading, as you cannot use it that way, even it you had the permission.

`/dev/ttyUSB0` is like a file. You can write to it (eg `echo "hello USB" > /dev/ttyUSB0`) and you can read from it (eg `cat /dev/ttyUSB0`).

If you want to use the port that way, you may need to use [stty](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stty&sektion=1) to set the the port's parameter (like the speed).

Another, simpler way, is to install and use a terminal programm like [minicom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicom).